# Adicionando JSF em projeto java

Tags: java, jsf-2.2

Criei um projeto Maven no IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2, defini como sendo um Web Application, e posteriormente instalei o JSF.

Antes de instalar o JSF o framework adicionou o arquivo index.jsp, o qual funciona normalmente, após adicionar o JSF criei um novo arquivo chamado index.xhtml, mas ao tentar abri-lo o Tomcat me retorna:

> HTTP Status 404 -
>   type Status report
>
> message
>
> description The requested resource is not available.
>
> Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M11

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.blue</groupId>
    <artifactId>Blue</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.4.Final</hibernate.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <javax.servlet.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet.version>
        <jsf.api.version>2.2.13</jsf.api.version>
        <jsf.impl.version>2.2.9</jsf.impl.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- HIBERNATE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JAVAX SERVLET -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf.api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf.impl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: como assim, instalou o JSF?
publique o seu POM.xml e
print a estrutura do seu projeto, incluindo a sua LIB.

Comment: Marcos, adicionei as informações solicitadas.

Comment: a resposta talvez ajude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, não entendi a versão da dependência do seu JSF. Tenta substituir pelo seguinte (ou pode escolher outra no repositório do maven).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Outra coisa que notei é que, se é um projeto Maven, tuas views não deveriam estar na pasta ***webapp***?

Seguindo a lógica de diretório:

- src/main/java: código fonte da aplicação organizado em pacotes;
- src/main/resources: recursos que a aplicação necessita;
- src/main/webapp: diretório para aplicações web, web.xml, imagens,
  HTML e XHTM's;
- src/test/java: testes unitários;

Também verifique se no arquivo de configuração **`web.xml`** está desta forma:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

O `*.xhtml` diz que o index a ser buscado será o **`index.xhtml`** e não o **`.jsp`**

PS - O JSF -*Java Server Faces* não se instala, é apenas uma especificação. Fica a cargo das implementações, a exemplo **Mojarra** e **MyFaces**, disponibilizar suas bibliotecas que atendem a este padrão da JCP.